# Show image on jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp

I can't show any image on my jsp.  I store pictures in a folder C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.18\webapps\ROOTuploads\   .  When I use html - it works. But whith jsp it doesn't work.

```
<img src=" <c:url value='${user.photoPath}' "  />
```

But it doesn't work.

How I solved it?

Comment: img src=" <c:url value='${user.photoPath}' "

Comment: I show user's data:

User name:${user.username}
User photoPath:${user.photoPath}

Comment: Did you check the source code of html which is being generated from your jsp file when you load your url?

Comment: remove the blanks <img src="<c:url value='${user.photoPath}'"  />

Comment: I removed blanks - but it doesn't work.

Comment: When I show photoPath on jsp :User photoPath:${user.photoPath}

It is rigth . But there is not image

Comment: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>                     
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
           uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>

User name:${user.username}
User photoPath:${user.photoPath}

<img src="<c:url value='${user.photoPath}'></c:url>" />


</body>
</html>
`

Comment: <img src="./ROOTuploads/<c:out value='${user.photoPath}'/>">

Comment: I think it is wrong..
in ${user.photoPath}  I store full path to image (C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.18\webapps\ROOTuploads\1.png )  .

Comment: Try using <img src="/uploads/1.png"  /> or try using  <img src='<c:url value="/uploads/1.png" />' />